# Generics making sure that T is of either of N Classes specified

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to create a list class to handle and raise events on `PropertyChanged` when any of the Properties changes.

My main class contains 3 Lists which all contain items of 3 different types

I would like to be able to do something like

```
public class MainClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomList<TextRecord> texts{get; set;};
    public CustomList<BinaryRecord> binaries{get; set;};
    public CustomList<MP3Record> Mp3s{get; set;};

    //implement INotifyPropertyChanged



}

    public class CustomList<T> where T:(TextRecord, BinaryRecord, MP3Record)
    {


    //code goes here

    }
```

How can I go about putting this restriction on my CustomList class please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what would be so wrong with someone creating a `CustomList<string>` or a `CustomList<int>`?

Comment: You can't do that if your classes don't inherit a base class (all 3 of them) or implement a common interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use the "OR" semantics on generic type parameters in a constraint, but you can create a special interface, have your target types implement it, and limit your generic instantiations to classes implementing the special interface:

```
public interface ICustomListable {
    // You can put some common properties in here
}
class TextRecord : ICustomListable {
    ...
}
class BinaryRecord : ICustomListable {
    ...
}
class MP3Record : ICustomListable {
    ...
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
public class CustomList<T> where T: ICustomListable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, no point answering after seeing this - this is the proper way to address this problem.